# How to add a Scope based User in IdentityServer3

Tags: .net, authentication, openid, identityserver3, user-permissions

I'm having two applications "App1" and "App2" and I configured `IdentityServer` for Single Sign On. I added Three Users "User1", "User2" and "User3".

- App1 <- User1 and User3
- App2 <- User2 and User3

"**User1**" has privilege to login to the application "**App1**" (Read Permission) (OR) How to achieve the Permission based access in some otherway...

"**User2**" has privilege to login to the application "**App2**" (Read Permission)

"**User1**" has privilege to login **both** the applications "**App1**" and "**App2**" (Read and Write Permission)

**Scope Configuration**:

*Scopes #1*:

```
new Scope
{
    Name = "App1",
    DisplayName = "API 1",
    Description = "API 1 features and data",
    Type = ScopeType.Resource
}
```

*Scopes #2*:

```
new Scope
{
    Name = "App2",
    DisplayName = "API 2",
    Description = "API 2 features and data",
    Type = ScopeType.Resource
}
```

**Client Configuration**:

*Client App #1*:

```
new Client
{
    ClientName = "Application #1",
    ClientId = "OneClient",
    ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
    {
        new Secret("madeupsecretApp1".Sha256())
    },
    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
    {
        "App1"
    }
}
```

*Client App #2*:

```
new Client
{
    ClientName = "Application #2",
    ClientId = "TwoClient",
    ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
    {
        new Secret("madeupsecretApp2".Sha256())
    },
    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
    {
        "App2"
    }
}
```

**User Configuration**:

*User #1*:

```
new InMemoryUser
{
    Subject = "1",
    Username = "User1",
    Password = "User1",
    Claims = new Claim[]
    {
        new Claim("Role", "App1")
    }
}
```

*User #2*:

```
new InMemoryUser
{
    Subject = "2",
    Username = "User2",
    Password = "User2",
    Claims = new Claim[]
    {
        new Claim("Role", "App2")
    }
}
```

*User #3*:

```
new InMemoryUser
{
    Subject = "3",
    Username = "User3",
    Password = "User3",
    Claims = new Claim[]
    {
        new Claim("Role", "App1"),
        new Claim("Role", "App2")
    }
}
```

I think I missed something in User Configuration or Client Configuration. Kindly assist me how to achieve this.

Comment: Scopes are not related to user authorization. IdentityServer is not about permissions but identity. https://leastprivilege.com/2016/12/16/identity-vs-permissions/

Comment: @leastprivilege: Thanks. Could you please assist me for the following Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42670557/identityserver3-redirect-logout-to-the-custom-url